# Reload Query Loop When FacetWP Uncheck

Tags: wordpress, facetwp

I am working on wordpress site with facetwp plugin. It already show the facet filter properly. When I filter it by checked the checkbox (on left sidebar) it will show the results. But when I uncheck that then it's not back to reload the content of wordpress (in this case I use AZ Listing plugin).

How to revert back to showing the old content (in this case is showing A-Z Listing) when uncheck the facetwp? This is the link: http://korexindo.com/k-market/

Comment: That's a broken link

Comment: You're right. sometime it broken. Please try again.

Comment: The link is still broken

Comment: Please try again